# queryselectorAll - find an element with more than one matching class

Tags: javascript

Using the JS queryselectorall method is it possible to select an elemnent of a particular tag name with 2 matching classes.

E.g. I have an element

```
<a class="classOne classTwo"></a>
```

using queryselectorall I can select on one classname:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.classOne");
```

how could this be extended so I can find all a tags with classOne AND classTwo?

document.querySelectorAll("a.classOne classTwo"); as expected doesn't seem to work

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The same way you would in CSS:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.classOne.classTwo");
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gcf6w/6/

Comment: @afk5min I'm not sure I am following, it does do exactly what the code implies, i.e. log the results to your console?

Answer (score 2):

Just add a dot..

```
document.querySelectorAll("a.classOne.classTwo")
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample query selector command that fetches all youtube src URL in one command.

```
document.querySelectorAll('yt-img-shadow.style-scope.ytd-thumbnail.no-transition  img').forEach(e=>console.log(e.src))
```