# JavaScript tag system: show only the divs that have all the classes listed in an array, else hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ecmascript-6

Please explain how to do this!

I want to be able to hide/show a div based on its classes and an array.

If `something` is in an array, then it will only show divs which have the `something` class.

If nothing is in an array, every div will be shown.

If `something` and `johnskeet` are in the array, then it will only show divs which have **both** the `something` and `johnskeet` classes.

Comment: Please share your HTML code where you want to implement the same ! Thanks

Comment: Take a look at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ then show some attempts please, kindly note SO is not a coding service

Comment: Try [https://jsfiddle.net/0o0v83kz/1/](this JSFiddle) and tell me what you think.

Comment: @Peanut, that link is broken.

Comment: @user338397, fixed link: [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0o0v83kz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, one option would to have all of the divs hidden by default and then use `document.querySelectorAll()` to apply an 'unhidden' style to each div that is in the array.

Here is a question that should help with selecting divs with multiple classes that should help as well.

[queryselectorAll - find an element with more than one matching class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598416/queryselectorall-find-an-element-with-more-than-one-matching-class)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the elements are initially shown, you only need to hide the undesired ones. You can insert a stylesheet with

```js
var rule = array.map(c => 'div:not(.' + CSS.escape(c) + ')').join()
           + '{display:none}';
sheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
```

```js
var array = ["something", "johnskeet"];
var rule = array.map(c => 'div:not(.' + CSS.escape(c) + ')').join() + '{display:none}';
var style = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(style);
var sheet = style.sheet;
sheet.insertRule(rule, 0);
```

```html
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="something johnskeet">something johnskeet</div>
<div class="something foo bar johnskeet">something johnskeet foo bar</div>
```

However, if some elements may already be hidden, you will need to set the desired display with higher specificity. The problem is that some elements are by default block-level, and some are inline-level. jQuery's [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can be helpful to detect that:

```
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle(array.every(c => this.classList.contains(c)));
});
```

```js
var array = ["something", "johnskeet"];
$('div').each(function() {
  $(this).toggle(array.every(c => this.classList.contains(c)));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="something johnskeet">something johnskeet</div>
<div class="something foo bar johnskeet">something johnskeet foo bar</div>
```

Another option would be [`display: revert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-4/#default), but it's not widely supported yet.

Comment: This would be highly inefficient for a large number of elements.

Comment: @Gothdo Yes, but reverting to the default display is not easy. jQuery does some tricks to do it. In CSS there is `revert`, but with small browser support.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to dynamically generate appropriate selector from the array, show all the matching elements and hide all other elements by default:

#### JavaScript

```
const classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
     ,selector = classes.map(x => '.' + x).join('')
$(selector).show()
```

#### CSS

```
div {
  display: none;
}
```

See [demo on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gwk4qddg/1/).

---

Alternatively, if you work on a high amount of elements, it would be better to generate appropriate style sheet in JavaScript:

```
const classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
     ,selector = classes.map(x => '.' + x).join('')
     ,$style = $(`<style>div {display: none;} div${selector} {display: block;}</style>`)

$('head').append($style)
```

To revert that, simply remove the `<style>` element by calling `$style.remove()`.

See [demo on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxLvcfsm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows with pure JS. Run the code multiple times to see the results for randomly generated `classArray`.

```js
var classes = ["something","johnskeet"],
 classArray = classes.reduce((p,c) => Math.random() > 0.5 ? p.concat(c) : p,[]),
       divs = document.querySelectorAll(".something, .johnskeet");

arrayStatus.textContent = "The current classes array is: " + JSON.stringify(classArray);

for (var div of divs) div.style.display = classArray.length === div.classList.length ? classArray.every(c => [...div.classList].includes(c)) ? "" : "none"
                                                                                     : !classArray.length ? "" : "none";
```

```css
.something           {background-color: paleGreen}
.johnskeet           {background-color: tomato}
.something.johnskeet {background-color: thistle}
```

```html
<p id="arrayStatus"></p>
<div class="something johnskeet">SJ</div>
<div class="johnskeet">J</div>
<div class="johnskeet">J</div>
<div class="something">S</div>
<div class="something">S</div>
<div class="johnskeet">J</div>
<div class="something johnskeet">SJ</div>
<div class="johnskeet">J</div>
<div class="something johnskeet">SJ</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to do anything fancy.

```
var array = ["something", "foo"];
```

Need to convert your array in such way that creates needed selector.

```
$('div').not("."+array.join(".")).hide();
```

Show element which has at-least once class from array.

```
$('div').not("."+array.join(",.")).hide();
```

If you've large amount of elements, you can use `each()` also.

```js
var array = ["something", "johnskeet"];
var selector="";
$.each(array, function(key, value){
  selector += "."+value;
});
console.log(selector);
$('div').not(selector).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">foo</div>
<div class="something">something</div>
<div class="something johnskeet">something johnskeet</div>
<div class="something foo bar johnskeet">something johnskeet foo bar</div>
<div class="dummy">dummy</div>
```